# How do I write current date and time to a sequential dataset using JCL?

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

Using z/OS 2.4, I have a Job that runs every morning that writes the status of several Db2 tablespaces into a sequential dataset, looking for any that are in a restricted state. (see code excerpt below) This JCL has run beautifully for years.

I would like to simply add the date and time to the top of the sequential dataset (followed by a blank line) so that I can easily know the last time the Job was run.

What is the best way to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Dave

```
//MYUSERND  JOB (16201,CCA25,227,72575),'DSPCPYPQ',
//     CLASS=1,MSGCLASS=X,MSGLEVEL=1,REGION=32M,NOTIFY=MYUSERN,TIME=99
/*JOBPARM TIME=10,LINES=050,CARDS=0000,COPIES=01
//*----------------------------------------------
//DISDB    EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,DYNAMNBR=20
//*----------------------------------------------
//STEPLIB   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=DB2.DBQ1.DSNA10.SDSNLOAD
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTSPRT DD DISP=SHR,DSN=MYUSERN.DB2.CMDOUTQ
//SYSTSIN  DD *
  DSN SYSTEM(DBQ1)
  -DISPLAY DB(DN*) SPACENAM(*) USE RESTRICT LIMIT(*)
...
//
```

Comment: There isn't really a best way, there are plenty of ways.  You need to decide which approach best fits your environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dave,

JCL does not create the time and date, it is the Utilities/Programs that create them. So here are 2 ways of creating the date and time.

Method : 1  You can the symbol conversion utility of z/OS to print the date and time

```
//STEP0100 EXEC PGM=EZACFSM1              
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                    
//SYSIN    DD *                           
CURRENT DATE IS  : &LYR4.-&LMON.-&LDAY    
CURRENT TIME IS  : &LHR.:&LMIN.:&LSEC     
/*
```

The sysout dd will contain the following

```
CURRENT DATE IS  : 2024-01-05
CURRENT TIME IS  : 11:11:36
```

Method: 2 Alternatively you can use DFSORT to display the same results

```
//STEP0100 EXEC PGM=SORT                             
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                               
//SORTIN   DD *                                      
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                               
//SYSIN    DD *                                      
  OPTION COPY                                        
  OUTFIL REMOVECC,                                   
  HEADER1=('CURRENT DATE IS  : ',DATE=(4MD-),/,      
           'CURRENT TIME IS  : ',TIME=(24:))         
/*
```

The SORTOUT DD will have the same information as shown above

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Kolusu! That puts the date and time in the SDSF log, but how would I add that exact same information to the output sequential dataset?

Comment: Dave,

You simply allocate SYSOUT or SORTOUT to a dataset.  Something like this 

//SYSOUT   DD DSN=&SYSUID..DISPLAY.DATE,         
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                     
//            SPACE=(TRK,(1,0)),UNIT=SYSDA,                 
//            DCB=(LRECL=80,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0,DSORG=PS)

Answer (score 3):

Since IJKEFT01 is batch TSO, you could add the TIME command before running DSN.

If you need to parse it and reformat, you could wrap it in a REXX exec, and call that instead before DSN

Execution of a REXX exec like:
/*REXX*/ say date('S') time('N');say

before DSN, would add something like

```
20240105 17:41:13
```

to the start of your SYSTSPRT output dataset.

Other formats are available -  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=functions-date

Answer (score 2):

Add the `time`command before the DSN DISPLAY command you are using.

It will display something like the following:

`IKJ56650I TIME-12:54:16 PM. CPU-00:00:54 SERVICE-735770 SESSION-35:19:15 JANUARY 5,2024`

It includes

- Cumulative CPU time (from LOGON)
- Cumulative session time (from LOGON)
- Total service units used, which includes:
- CPU service units - A measure of task execution time.
- I/O service units - A measure of SMF data set activity.
- Storage service units - A measure of the page frame usage.
- Local time of day

If you want something more formatted then REXX is your best bet.